Дергание видосов в ютубе на ОС Linux Ubuntu
Смотрю видос в ютубчике но оно дергается слегка и потом становится нормально но через примерно 15 сек видео опять дергается. Что мне делать? Вот характеристики моего ноута: процессор- intel i3 7020u, видеокарта - intel uhd graphics 620, оперативка - 4ГБ. Буду рад если кто то поможет. Может проблема с драйверами?

ну так посмотрите сначала что за драйвер стоит lspci -v | awk '/VGA/,/^$/'

https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/122590/intel-core-i3-7020u-processor-3m-cache-2-30-ghz.html проц не очень свежий, 18года, и скорее всего встроенная видеокарточка не поддерживает декодирования vp8/vp9 формат в котором ютуб по умолчанию и отдаёт видеопоток. Посмотрите вывод команды vainfo там должна быть инфа о поддержке разных форматов. Если там нету упоминаний о vp9 то декодирования видео ложиться на проц со всеми вытекающими, в таком случае поищите аддон для браузера который бы запрашивал у YouTube H.264 вместо VP8/VP9

И в FF и в Хроме одинаково плохо?
